# Order by multiple columns from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I want to make merge 2 tables, and then do `ORDER BY`, first to order them by `top` column, so that products with value 1 in `top` show up first in record set.

Afterwards, I want to order them by `premium` column, so that products with value 1 go right after `top` products.

After that, I want the rest of products to order by `pub_date` from table `items`, and products with value 1 in column `highlighted` should not be shown directly bellow `top` and `premium` items.

Since original tables are full of unnecessary info, here's the stripped down versions:

```
Table `items`:
+-------+------------+--------+
| pk_id | pub_date   | author |
+-------+------------+--------+
|     1 | 2013-06-11 | John   |
|     2 | 2013-06-12 | Mike   |
|     3 | 2013-06-25 | Seth   |
|     4 | 2013-06-11 | Drew   |
|     5 | 2013-06-13 | Joe    |
+-------+------------+--------+

Table `paid_items`:
+-------+-----+---------+-------------+--------+
| fk_id | top | premium | highlighted | active |
+-------+-----+---------+-------------+--------+
|     2 |   1 |       0 |           0 |      1 |
|     3 |   0 |       0 |           1 |      1 |
|     4 |   0 |       1 |           0 |      1 |
|     5 |   0 |       0 |           1 |      1 |
+-------+-----+---------+-------------+--------+
```

EDIT:
Here's the pseudo (or whatever) of what I want to accomplish:

```
PRODUCTS_LIST>
    PRODUCTS WITH TOP VALUE
    PRODUCTS WITH PREMIUM VALUE
    PRODUCTS ORDERED BY PUB_DATE>
        PRODUCT WITH NO HIGHLIGHTED VALUE
        PRODUCT WITH NO HIGHLIGHTED VALUE
        PRODUCT WITH HIGHLIGHTED VALUE
        PRODUCT WITH NO HIGHLIGHTED VALUE
        PRODUCT WITH HIGHLIGHTED VALUE
        ...
```

A striped down version of how the recordset should look like, focus is on `highlighted` column:

```
mysql> select pk_id, highlighted from items left join paid_items on items.pk_id
= paid_items.fk_id order by pub_date desc;
+-------+-------------+
| pk_id | highlighted |
+-------+-------------+
|     3 |           1 |
|     5 |           1 |
|     2 |           0 |
|     1 |        NULL |
|     4 |           0 |
+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: So you want to merge `items` and `paid_items` table?

Comment: Yup. This is actually striped down version of 2 big tables, so you don't have wall of text in SO question. What I need is to order it all by `top`, `premium` and `pub_date`, but not to take `highlighted` in consideration - it's just a piece of info that I use later for product printing.

So it will return a record set containing `top` and `premium` products, order them by these 2 columns, and after that return other products ordered by `pub_date`, no matter if it's highlighted or not.

Answer (score 0):

Simple select would be:-

```
SELECT *
FROM items a
LEFT OUTER JOIN paid_items b
ON a.pk_id = b.fk_id
ORDER BY b.top, b.premium, a.pub_date
```

but I presume you know that already.

However I am unsure what you mean by *products with value 1 in column highlighted should not be shown directly bellow top and premium items* . Do you want these excluded, or displayed at the bottom of the list. Could you put some example output in your question?

Comment: Change the LEFT OUTER JOIN to an INNER JOIN to exclude records where there is no matching record on paid_items

Comment: Afraid I can't see how that order matches up with your requirements and the sample data. For example you say to order by top firstly and the only record with top of 1 is record 2, yet that lands up 3rd in your list.

Comment: That's an example (my edit of the question) of ordering only by `pub_date`, just to show you how I would like my `highlighted` column to look like

Comment: If the only difference is the columns required, then change it from SELCT * to SELECT a.pk_id, b.highlighted . If you want highlighted first then just put b.highlighted as the first order by clause